# PHP Encryption, encrypts with empty line in mind

Tags: php

I'm working with some encryption in PHP that's being accessed by some c# code,

When I sha1 Encrypt the following: `test1:test1:apple`, 
every online generator will return: `8ee27a0e9368d2835b3fdeb4b50caf1d8f790314`
However, when I run my PHP script it returns `296b39344a6eb9d88c3bb1122f5941f0bcf3b0c2` instead. Because essentially it's adding an empty line along with the string (`test1:test1:apple`) that I'm encrypting.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? It's not neccesarily the worst thing in the world, it's just extremely annoying.

The code I'm using is pretty simple:

```
function GetRandomWord()
{
$file = "../Core/nouns0.txt";
$file_arr = file($file);
$num_lines = count($file_arr);
$last_index = $num_lines -1;

$rand_index = rand(0, $last_index);
$rand_text = $file_arr[$rand_index];

return $rand_text;
}

$enc = GetRandomWord();
$encrypted = sha1("$username:$password:$enc");
echo $encrypted;
```

which gets caught in c# by a script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you don't consider newline to be part of input you could remove all occurrences using str_replace(mb_ereg_replace if you expect unicode input)

Comment: one of the variables has the newline $username $password or $enc

Comment: @SSPoke both user variables are inserted by c# `PHPClient.Login("http://localhost/ext_connect_sql/requestlogin.php", "test1", "test1");`

and $enc is a return statement from a function.

Comment: @niceman I tried using str_replace, `$encrypted = str_replace("\n", '', $encrypted);` however it returns the exact same thing

Comment: change `return $rand_text;` to `return trim($rand_text);`

Comment: @DavidNap maybe newline isn't `\n` in your platform but something else like `\r\n`, try to inspect the characters of the input to see which characters should be removed

Comment: The hash doesn't have the newline it's before the hash is made that's why the hashes are different, so it must only need one of those variables that make the sha1 function

Comment: try `function check($string) { if(strpos($string, "\n") || strpos($string, "\r\n")) echo $string."has new line"; }` `check($username); check($password); check($enc);`

Comment: Yes I tested `test:test:apple (new line)` gives the same bad hash so the problem is in `$enc`  the word is added with a new line so the problem is with `GetRandomWord()` replace  `return $rand_text;` with `return str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $rand_text);`

Answer (score 1):

@IłyaBursov their answer helped! I changed the GetRandomWord() function's return statement to
`return trim($rand_text);`

Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious why you would not just avoid the newline in the first place instead of removing it afterwards?

Comment: @miken32 for some reason, the return statement automatically would add an empty line, to the variable it returns. I have no idea as to why it does this.

Comment: I did @miken32 but I guess I didn't quite catch what you meant, as the file that is being read doesn't have any empty lines?

Comment: There's nothing about empty lines in my answer. A linefeed (often represented as "\n") is a character that indicates the end of a line. It's included in the output from `file()` unless you say otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

[`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) will read each line of a file into an array. It reads the entire line, *including the linefeed at the end*. If you don't want this behaviour, use the second argument to say so:

```
$file_arr = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```